# Artemis master service got shutdown with IO Error

Tags: activemq-artemis

Below is  the scenario from our client environment so that it may help you to give the inputs as required:

1. Master and slave were shutdown
2. After that only Master service was started and client missed (might have forgotten) to start the Slave service
3. Master got shutdown with the below IO error message after sometime.

```
2020-12-07 10:45:40,717 ERROR [org.apache.activemq.artemis.journal] AMQ144002: Error pushing opened file: ActiveMQIOErrorException[errorType=IO_ERROR message=AMQ149000: failed to rename file activemq-data-495656.amq.tmp to activemq-data-495656.amq]
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.io.AbstractSequentialFile.renameTo(AbstractSequentialFile.java:160) [artemis-journal-2.11.0.jar:2.11.0]
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.journal.impl.JournalFilesRepository.createFile0(JournalFilesRepository.java:633) [artemis-journal-2.11.0.jar:2.11.0]
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.journal.impl.JournalFilesRepository.createFile(JournalFilesRepository.java:574) [artemis-journal-2.11.0.jar:2.11.0]
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.journal.impl.JournalFilesRepository.takeFile(JournalFilesRepository.java:535) [artemis-journal-2.11.0.jar:2.11.0]
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.journal.impl.JournalFilesRepository.pushOpenedFile(JournalFilesRepository.java:486) [artemis-journal-2.11.0.jar:2.11.0]
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.journal.impl.JournalFilesRepository$1.run(JournalFilesRepository.java:92) [artemis-journal-2.11.0.jar:2.11.0]
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.utils.actors.OrderedExecutor.doTask(OrderedExecutor.java:42) [artemis-commons-2.11.0.jar:2.11.0]
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.utils.actors.OrderedExecutor.doTask(OrderedExecutor.java:31) [artemis-commons-2.11.0.jar:2.11.0]
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.utils.actors.ProcessorBase.executePendingTasks(ProcessorBase.java:66) [artemis-commons-2.11.0.jar:2.11.0]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [rt.jar:1.8.0_271]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [rt.jar:1.8.0_271]
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.utils.ActiveMQThreadFactory$1.run(ActiveMQThreadFactory.java:118) [artemis-commons-2.11.0.jar:2.11.0]

2020-12-07 10:45:40,717 WARN  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ222010: Critical IO Error, shutting down the server. file=NULL, message=unable to open : ActiveMQIOErrorException[errorType=IO_ERROR message=AMQ149000: failed to rename file activemq-data-495656.amq.tmp to activemq-data-495656.amq]
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.io.AbstractSequentialFile.renameTo(AbstractSequentialFile.java:160) [artemis-journal-2.11.0.jar:2.11.0]
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.journal.impl.JournalFilesRepository.createFile0(JournalFilesRepository.java:633) [artemis-journal-2.11.0.jar:2.11.0]
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.journal.impl.JournalFilesRepository.createFile(JournalFilesRepository.java:574) [artemis-journal-2.11.0.jar:2.11.0]
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.journal.impl.JournalFilesRepository.takeFile(JournalFilesRepository.java:535) [artemis-journal-2.11.0.jar:2.11.0]
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.journal.impl.JournalFilesRepository.pushOpenedFile(JournalFilesRepository.java:486) [artemis-journal-2.11.0.jar:2.11.0]
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.journal.impl.JournalFilesRepository$1.run(JournalFilesRepository.java:92) [artemis-journal-2.11.0.jar:2.11.0]
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.utils.actors.OrderedExecutor.doTask(OrderedExecutor.java:42) [artemis-commons-2.11.0.jar:2.11.0]
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.utils.actors.OrderedExecutor.doTask(OrderedExecutor.java:31) [artemis-commons-2.11.0.jar:2.11.0]
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.utils.actors.ProcessorBase.executePendingTasks(ProcessorBase.java:66) [artemis-commons-2.11.0.jar:2.11.0]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [rt.jar:1.8.0_271]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [rt.jar:1.8.0_271]
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.utils.ActiveMQThreadFactory$1.run(ActiveMQThreadFactory.java:118) [artemis-commons-2.11.0.jar:2.11.0]
```

So we would like to know if the rename of the file failures is due to the file system issues (or) the slave being in stopped could also cause this. If it needs additional question to be raised we will do the same.

Comment: Attaching  the logs and broker.xml which  will be helpful https://gist.github.com/sandeepmandava-smarsh/775783913e515cdbf3c1a824a3275d92

https://gist.github.com/sandeepmandava-smarsh/feb24d2dac60f44ae7ba9fcede22660c

Comment: Did my answer address your question? If so, please mark it as correct to help other users who may have this same question in the future. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The slave being stopped would certainly *not* cause this problem. Even if it is running the slave won't access any of the journal files if the master is running because the master will hold a lock. To be clear, the master has no strict dependency on the slave. If the slave isn't running the master will simply operate normally.

Therefore the only conclusion that seems at all plausible is that something went wrong with file system.

There is also always the possibility of a bug, although I've never seen any bugs reported for this particular operation. If you are able to reproduce this failure (even intermittently) then please file [a Jira](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ARTEMIS).